# "Not having a smartphone ... is more pros than cons." Why is this sentence wrong?

Tags: grammaticality, word-order, auxiliary-verbs

> Not having a smartphone in your daily life **is more** pros than cons.

Should change it to

> There **are more** pros than cons to not having a smartphone in your daily life.

But I don't understand why *pros and cons* can't be put at the back of a sentence. It doesn't sound wrong to me.

Please help me out, thanks!

Comment: Using 'is' as a deleted form of 'is a situation that has' is rather more than a mere re-ordering of a sentence. You might get away with it in informal conversation.

Comment: "has more pros than cons" is clearer than "is more."  Or "is more positive than negative."  Just like "The painting is more blues than reds" doesn't make sense, but "The painting is more blue than red" or "The painting has more blues than reds" do make sense. The "is more $noun" construction doesn't work since "more" is an adverb and needs to modify an adjective, and "pros" is a plural noun, not an adjective.

Comment: I've upvoted Edwin Ashworth and jejorda2's comments, but in case it's not totally clear, "Not having a smartphone in your life *has* more pros than cons" is a perfectly acceptable sentence. You *can* put "pros and cons" at the end, but you should use "has" instead of "is."

Comment: @jejorda2 you can use *more* with nouns, it doesn't need an adjective; e.g.  "I have more *money* than you" is fine. "There *is* **more money** in this account than in that". "There *are* **more pros than cons...**"

Comment: @Mari-LouA Yes, but then "more" is an adjective.  "My checking account is more dollars than my savings account" isn't right.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth  thanks for answering and helping me out!

Comment: @Mari-Lou A thanks for the edit and helping me out!

Comment: @TeacherKSHuang thank you !! was wondering if I can use has instead.

Comment: @jejorda2 thanks for taking your time to answer!!

Comment: Heh, as jejorda was saying, you almost have to use "has" instead of "is."

Comment: The first example is not "wrong", it's just "informal".  One or more words has been elided (several options there), but it is perfectly understandable.

Comment: @TeacherKSHuang ok thanks!! What part in a grammar book should I check for this kind of grammatic issue? Want to learn more about it! Thanks!!

Comment: @CYU, this isn't from a grammar book, but I think its comparisons are still useful here for understanding using "to have" or "to be": [Is "not having a smartphone in your daily life" limited or continuous](http://dragosroua.com/to-have-versus-to-be/)?

Answer (score 2):

You can organize your sentence both ways, it is your grammar that is wrong.

"There **are more pros than cons** to not having a smartphone in your daily life" is correct.

"Not having a smart phone in your daily life **has more pros than cons**" is also correct.

Comment: @PeterShor thanks for answering! so why is it ungrammatical??

Comment: The OP's original sentence *"Not having a smartphone is more pros than cons"* has a singular subject, so this discussion of *is* versus *are* in your answer is very misleading.